# how to merge 2 letters (in math mode)

Tags: math-mode, letters

I have a special operator which is now denoted using 2-letter name MR. I would like to merge them into special symbol where these two letters merged, sharing vertical bar. Similar to Æ.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Something like this? The negative kerning values are a guess, however. (Improvement suggestions by Werner and egreg, many thanks to both of them!)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareMathOperator{\mr}{M\MRkern R}
\newcommand{\MRkern}{%
  \mkern-6.5mu
  \mathchoice{}{}{\mkern0.2mu}{\mkern0.5mu}%
}

\begin{document}

$\mr$ $\scriptstyle\mr$ $\scriptscriptstyle\mr$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I am using 'acmsmall' document type and it it is using different math font in which it does not look as good as in your pictures above. The main problem is that M's sides in their font are slanted. Any suggestions how to fix this?

Comment: Wow this is so cool, MR are my initials too. Is there a way to vectorize it and use it as a logo?

Comment: @noibe: well, you could use `standalone` class and let it convert to a vector format other than `.pdf`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer the output using `standalone` class is not the best as you can see [here](https://imgur.com/a/Uim31r4), the bottom part of the R gets cut away.

Comment: Is there a way to tell `standalone` class to be a little more generous?

Comment: @noibe: Well, I never use `standalone` really. Obtaining vectorized output is not my main goal

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Ok thanks. Btw, how should I change the command to use it in text and not in math environments?